# mongodb select all fields which is not null or empty string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have mongodb document which has data like this:

```
{
  "_id": "ObjectId(\"5e09db41d4ccee7f500f7326\")",
  "time": "ISODate(\"2019-12-30T09:10:53Z\")",
  "syslog_fac": 23,
  "syslog_sever": 6,
  "syslog_tag": "",
  "procid": "",
  "pid": "-",
  "status": "Allowed",
  "logtype": "Firewall Logs",
  "date": "2019-12-30",
  "Module": "01UM",
  "Desc": "Theuserloggedout.(UserName",
  "Severity_Level": "6",
  "Vsys": "public",
  "SourceIP": "10.10.0.57",
  "ParentGroup": "/netgrup.com.tr",
  "LogonTime": "2019/12/3014:07:20",
  "LogoutTime": "2019/12/3014:10:53",
  "ObversePackets": "0",
  "ObverseBytes": "0",
  "ReversePackets": "0",
  "ReverseBytes": "0",
  "LogoutReason": "AnIPaddressconflictoccurred",
  "VSys": "",
  "PolicyName": "",
  "Country": "",
  "DestinationIP": "",
  "SourcePort": "",
  "DestinationPort": "",
  "SourceZone": "",
  "DestinationZone": "",
  "User": "",
  "Protocol": "",
  "ApplicationName": "",
  "Profile": "",
  "Type": "",
  "Category": "",
  "SubCategory": "",
  "Page": "",
  "Host": "",
  "Referer": "",
  "Item": "",
  "Action": "",
  "level": "",
  "SourceNatIP": "",
  "SourceNatPort": "",
  "BeginTime": "",
  "EndTime": "",
  "SendPkts": 0,
  "SendBytes": 0,
  "RcvPkts": 0,
  "RcvBytes": 0,
  "SourceVpnID": "",
  "DestinationVpnID": "",
  "CloseReason": "",
  "Task": "",
  "Ip": "",
  "VpnName": "",
  "AuthenticationMethod": "",
  "Command": "",
  "user-name": "",
  "attack-type": "",
  "interface": "",
  "packet-count": "",
  "rate-number": "",
  "file-name": "",
  "file-type": "",
  "direction": "",
  "detect-type": "",
  "virus-name": "",
  "signature-id": "",
  "event-number": "",
  "target": "",
  "role": "",
  "user": ""
}
```

As you see there are a lot of fields which have an empty string or 0 , so  what  I want to do is to select only columns that have value  except 0 or empty string.

this is my code  that I am using to execute query from laravel but return nothings  , when I apply that code in mongo directly I get correct data  , and return exactly what I want , but return nothings from laravel ,

> $data = Logss::raw(function($collection)use ($_id)
>             {
>
> ```
> return $collection->aggregate([
>  [ '$match' => ['_id'=>'ObjectId(5e09dc63715d622be622c639)']],
>      [
>         '$replaceRoot'=> [
>             'newRoot'=>[
>                 '$arrayToObject'=>[
>                     '$filter'=> [
>                         'input'=> [ '$objectToArray'=>'$$ROOT' ],
>                         'cond'=> [
>                             '$and'=> [
>                                 [ '$ne'=> [ '$$this.v', "" ] ],
>                                 [ '$ne'=>[ '$$this.v', 0 ] ]
>                             ]
>                         ]
>                     ]
>                 ]
>             ]
>         ]
>    ]
>
>
> ]);
> });
> ```

Comment: I am not sure how you are finding this document (search) but you can do all this in your `projection` with conditionals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run below query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: ObjectId(...) } },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $arrayToObject: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" },
                        cond: {
                            $and: [
                                { $ne: [ "$$this.v", "" ] },
                                { $ne: [ "$$this.v", 0 ] }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

The idea is pretty simple: you start with [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) to get all the fields as an array. Then you can run [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to remove all zeros and whitespaces and convert that array back to an object [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) promoting it to the root level ([$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html)).

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AhVVXhdF79X)

Comment: thank you for your replay,  I applied this code in my database and worked fine , but what if I want to get for only one record (where id=23423423432) it not working when adding match condition

Comment: @stackover modifed my answer, just use `$match` before `$replaceRoot`